# CLI PHP Is there a command line jpg image viewer for that will work in both OS X and Windows?

Tags: php, jpeg, command-line-interface

I am trying to view, one by one, photos in a directory, and based on what they are, move them to another directory. I have not found a way to view the images with the loop in my CLI PHP. Ideally the viewer would work on both OS X and Windows 7 command line window. But if has to be different viewer, I can deal with it. I asked this earlier but was my first post on Stackoverflow and may not have presented the question clearly initially.

The code ...

```
<?php
system("stty cbreak");

// View the jpg images one at a time
$files = glob("images/*.jpg");
foreach($files as $jpg){
//    echo "<img src='$jpg'></br>";
  echo "view image somehow" . PHP_EOL;

echo "The jpg variable equals '$jpg'" . PHP_EOL;

// show them a message to enter letter for category
echo "Enter the category, a(family), r(friends), c(coworkers), d(delete), ctrl-letter(two folders)" . PHP_EOL;

// the script will wait here until the user has entered something and hit ENTER
$category = read_stdin();

// This will display the category message including the category they entered.
echo "You chose $category . Next photo" . PHP_EOL;

switch ($category) {
    case "a":
        echo "$category equals family" . PHP_EOL;
        rename("$jpg", "images/sorted/family/$jpg");
        cli_beep();
        break;
    case "r":
        echo "$category equals friends" . PHP_EOL;
        rename("$jpg", "images/sorted/friends/$jpg");
        break;
    case "c":
        echo "$category equals coworkers" . PHP_EOL;
        rename("$jpg", "images/sorted/coworkers/$jpg");
        break;
    default:
       echo "$category is not equal to a,r, or c" . PHP_EOL;
 }

}

// our function to read from the command line
function read_stdin()
{
        $fr=fopen("php://stdin","r");   // open our file pointer to read from stdin
        $input = fread($fr,1);        // read a maximum of 1 character
        $input = rtrim($input);         // trim any trailing spaces.
        fclose ($fr);                   // close the file handle
        return $input;                  // return the text entered
}

function cli_beep()
{
    echo "\x07";
}


system("stty sane");
?>
```

Comment: view, as in, convert to ASCII art???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to view jpg images with a command line PHP program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936086/how-to-view-jpg-images-with-a-command-line-php-program)

Comment: How do you want to view an image in a command line interface?

Comment: I would like for the program to open a window with the photo in it and I enter my keystroke to move the image file to the desired folder, based on

Comment: what category I decide the photo is. It is a photo sorting program. Not ASCII art.